# getting 505 error while DEBUG = True while pushing to heroku

Tags: python, django, debugging, heroku

I'm pushing my django project to heroku.

This is what is perturbing me at the moment.

in my settings.py

when I turn leave my debug like this

```
DEBUG = False
```

and i run the command to push it heroku.

I will get a `505 error`.

but when I reverse it to

```
DEBUG = True
```

it will run smoothly.

Meanwhile, I already did

```
heroku config:add DEBUG=False
```

and it's reflecting on my heroku's `reveal config var`

What could be the problem? Because I'm trying to turn off debug while in production

Answer (score 0):

Oops. After posting this, I read it again and had this thought.

Since it is always required to `DEBUG = False` while deploying django to production, I already did that by using `heroku config:add DEBUG=False` command.

The `DEBUG=True` in my settings.py will only run in the local environment.

I may be wrong.